# getting all snapshot and volume details of AWS account using AWS lambda and python sdk

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, xlsxwriter

**Hi,
I am trying to get all snapshot details and volumes details from AWS account. My code is working perfectly but I dont know for some reason it is showing snapshot and volume of just 'us-east-1' and 'ap-southeast-1' region. However I have resources available in other regions also.**

```
import xlsxwriter
import boto3  
import collections  
import datetime  
from time import gmtime, strftime  
import smtplib  
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart  
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase  
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText  
from email import Encoders  
import os

#lambda function beginning
def worker_handler(event, context): 

    date_fmt = strftime("%Y_%m_%d", gmtime())
    #Give your file path
    filepath ='/tmp/CM_AWS_Resources_' + date_fmt + '.xlsx'
    #Give your filename
    filename ='CM_AWS_Resources_' + date_fmt + '.xlsx'
    # xlsx_file = open(filepath,'w+')
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filepath)
    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('snapshots')
    worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('volumes')

    volumeHeader = ['volume id','snapshot id','creation date','Description','size','Region']
    snapshotsHeader=['volume id','state','size','Region']
    headVolSize=1
    row=0
    col=0
    while headVolSize <= len(volumeHeader):
        for i in volumeHeader:
            worksheet1.write(row,col,i)
            col+=1
            headVolSize=headVolSize+1

    headSnapSize=1
    row=0
    col=0
    while headSnapSize <= len(snapshotsHeader):
        for i in snapshotsHeader:
            worksheet2.write(row,col,i)
            col+=1
            headSnapSize=headSnapSize+1

    while headVolSize <= len(volumeHeader):
        for i in volumeHeader:
                worksheet1.write(row,col,headVolSize)
                worksheet1.write(row,col+1,i)
                row +=1
                headVolSize=headVolSize+1
                j=j+1
    ec = boto3.client('ec2')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    ec2Res = boto3.resource('ec2')
    regions = ec.describe_regions().get('Regions',[] )
    for region in regions:
        reg=region['RegionName']
        regname='REGION :' + reg
        # print regname
        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=reg) 

        snapshots=ec2.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['***',],).get('Snapshots',[])
        if len(snapshots) >0 :
            print "snapshots : " + str(len(snapshots)) + " " + reg
            j=1
            while j <= len(snapshots):
                row=0
                col=0
                for i in snapshots:
                        # print type(i['StartTime'])
                        date1 = i['StartTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                        # print "row : " + str(row) + " col : " + str(col) 
                        # print i['VolumeId'] + str(row) + "," + str(col) + " " + i['SnapshotId'] + " " +str(row) + "," + str(col+1) + " " +  str(i['StartTime']) + " " + " " +str(row) + "," + str(col+2) + " " + i['Description'] + " " +" " +str(row) + "," + str(col+3) + " " + str(i['VolumeSize']) + " " +str(row) + "," + str(col+4) + " " + reg + " " +str(row) + "," + str(col+5)
                        worksheet1.write(row,col,i['VolumeId'])
                        worksheet1.write(row,col+1,i['SnapshotId'])
                        worksheet1.write(row,col+2,date1)
                        worksheet1.write(row,col+3,i['Description'])
                        worksheet1.write(row,col+4,i['VolumeSize'])
                        worksheet1.write(row,col+5,reg)
                        row +=1
                        j=j+1
            # else:
            #     print "do nothing"
        ec2volumes = ec2.describe_volumes().get('Volumes',[])
        if len(ec2volumes) >0 :
            #if reg=='ap-south-1':
            print "volumes : " + str(len(ec2volumes)) + " " + reg
            j=1
            while j <= len(ec2volumes):
                row=0
                col=0
                for i in ec2volumes:
                        # print type(i['StartTime'])
                        # print "row : " + str(row) + " col : " + str(col) 
                        # print i['VolumeId'] + str(row) + "," + str(col) + " " + i['SnapshotId'] + " " +str(row) + "," + str(col+1) + " " +  str(i['StartTime']) + " " + " " +str(row) + "," + str(col+2) + " " + i['Description'] + " " +" " +str(row) + "," + str(col+3) + " " + str(i['VolumeSize']) + " " +str(row) + "," + str(col+4) + " " + reg + " " +str(row) + "," + str(col+5)
                        worksheet2.write(row,col,i['VolumeId'])
                        worksheet2.write(row,col+1,i['State'])
                        worksheet2.write(row,col+2,i['Size'])
                        worksheet2.write(row,col+3,reg)
                        row +=1
                        j=j+1


    workbook.close()

    ses_user = "***"
    ses_pwd = "***"

    def mail(fromadd,to, subject, text, attach):
       msg = MIMEMultipart()
       msg['From'] = fromadd
       msg['To'] = to
       msg['Subject'] = subject
       msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
       part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
       part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
       Encoders.encode_base64(part)
       part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
       msg.attach(part)
       mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 587)
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.starttls()
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.login(ses_user, ses_pwd)
       mailServer.sendmail(fromadd, to, msg.as_string())
       # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
       mailServer.close()

    date_fmt = strftime("%Y_%m_%d", gmtime())
    #Give your file path
    filepath ='/tmp/CM_AWS_Resources_' + date_fmt + '.xlsx'
    #Give your filename
    mailTO=['***']
    for i in mailTO:
        mail("***",i,"Details for unimportant snapshot deletion","PFA for the AWS resource of AWS account.",filepath)

    s3.Object('bucketname', filename).put(Body=open(filepath, 'rb'))
```

Comment: did you check Roles assigned to lambda are given the rights to perform cross region ec2.describe_*()  .

Answer (score 0):

I found out the mistake in my code. Everytime row value was updated to 1 in "**for region in regions:**" section and thus I was getting only two region value. So I declared 2 different values for row and column of both snapshot loop and volume loop.So the solution was I declared **rowSnap=1 rowVol=1** separately and it worked correctly.

```
rowSnap=1
rowVol=1
regions = ec.describe_regions().get('Regions',[] )
for region in regions:
    reg=region['RegionName']
    regname='REGION :' + reg
    # print regname
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=reg) 
    snapshots=ec2.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['**',],).get('Snapshots',[])
    if len(snapshots) >0 :
        print "snapshots : " + str(len(snapshots)) + " " + reg
        j=1
        col=0
        while j <= len(snapshots):
            for i in snapshots:
                    date1 = i['StartTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    worksheet1.write(rowSnap,col,i['VolumeId'])
                    worksheet1.write(rowSnap,col+1,i['SnapshotId'])
                    worksheet1.write(rowSnap,col+2,date1)
                    worksheet1.write(rowSnap,col+3,i['Description'])
                    worksheet1.write(rowSnap,col+4,i['VolumeSize'])
                    worksheet1.write(rowSnap,col+5,reg)
                    rowSnap +=1
                    j=j+1
    ec2volumes = ec2.describe_volumes().get('Volumes',[])
    if len(ec2volumes) >0 :
        #if reg=='ap-south-1':
        print "volumes : " + str(len(ec2volumes)) + " " + reg
        j=1
        col=0
        while j <= len(ec2volumes):
            # row=0
            # col=0
            for i in ec2volumes:
                    worksheet2.write(rowVol,col,i['VolumeId'])
                    worksheet2.write(rowVol,col+1,i['State'])
                    worksheet2.write(rowVol,col+2,i['Size'])
                    worksheet2.write(rowVol,col+3,reg)
                    rowVol +=1
                    j=j+1


workbook.close()
```